# Nested CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have one CASE WHEN condition (CompanyGUID and LineGUID) and I need 4 different calculations with 4 different columns. 
The calculation works fine, but I just wonder is any way to make it more convenient? like for example maybe using COALESCE trick in this case?

```
CASE WHEN dbo.tblCompanyLocations.CompanyGUID = '29634AF7-D0A2-473D-9574-405C23E10F02' 
      AND dbo.tblQuotes.LineGUID = '1CB72920-B3FC-4822-8030-37B50A2810EB' 
     THEN isnull(ddaWC.archexMod,1) 
     END as ExperienceMod, 

CASE WHEN dbo.tblCompanyLocations.CompanyGUID = '29634AF7-D0A2-473D-9574-405C23E10F02' 
      AND dbo.tblQuotes.LineGUID = '1CB72920-B3FC-4822-8030-37B50A2810EB'           
     THEN case when convert(int,ddawc.premModTtl) <= 0 then 1 
               when convert(int,ddawc.premModTtl) >= 0 
                 then (1 + ddaWC.premschmod / ddawc.premModTtl) end 
     END as ScheduleMod,

CASE WHEN dbo.tblCompanyLocations.CompanyGUID = '29634AF7-D0A2-473D-9574-405C23E10F02' 
      AND dbo.tblQuotes.LineGUID = '1CB72920-B3FC-4822-8030-37B50A2810EB'   
     THEN   isnull(ddaWC.TMpercent,1) END  as  TerritoryMod, 

CASE WHEN dbo.tblCompanyLocations.CompanyGUID = '29634AF7-D0A2-473D-9574-405C23E10F02' 
      AND dbo.tblQuotes.LineGUID = '1CB72920-B3FC-4822-8030-37B50A2810EB' 
     THEN case when convert(int,ddaWC.SchedPercent) = 0 or 
                    ddaWC.SchedPercent is not null 
                 then (isnull(ddaWC.archexMod,1) 
                     * (convert(decimal(5,2),isnull(ddaWC.SchedPercent,1)))) 
                     * isnull(ddaWC.TMpercent,1)
               when ddaWC.SchedPercent is null 
                  then 1 END 
     END as EffectiveMod
```

Comment: What do you mean by more convenient?  Having to type less code?

Comment: Sorry, I mean can I use one time (CompanyGUID and LineGUID)  and as a result have 4 different columns?

Comment: Lets just say better way, more professional way of writing this query

Comment: I see case statements like this in many production environments, no real issues there.  You can make a mapping table and inner join to it instead (a table being a bit easier to maintain than code modification, lets you move on-going changes to someone who can enter a line into a table instead of modifying sql code)

Comment: Are you only interested in the records that match the case or are you pulling other records as well which would have null values for these columns?

Comment: you could eliminate some unnecessary logical statements, like using both `>= 0` and `<=0` in same case statements. That could be replaced with one comparison and an else...

Comment: yes, im interested in only records that match the case statement cause I am pulling other records as well, which would have NULL values

Comment: If this code is in a Stored proc, you could make it more readable by declaring variables (with meaningful names) to hold the Guids and use the variables in the code.

Comment: in `convert(int,ddaWC.SchedPercent) = 0 or 
                    ddaWC.SchedPercent is not null`,  if `ddaWC.SchedPercent` was null, then  `convert(int,ddaWC.SchedPercent)` will also be null, so isn't the `or` redundant ?

Comment: Hi Oleg, is this question solved? Do you need further help?

Comment: Yes, I got my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? The `OUTER APPLY` will perform a row-based select which return `NULLs` in case of your condition not being fullfilled. Otherwise it will return the same values you've specified. This will only work, if you really need the same logic for all columns.

```
SELECT otherColumn
      ,ConditionalColumns.*
FROM YourTable
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT isnull(ddaWC.archexMod,1) as ExperienceMod, 
           case when convert(int,ddawc.premModTtl) <= 0 then 1 
                when convert(int,ddawc.premModTtl) >= 0 
                then (1 + ddaWC.premschmod / ddawc.premModTtl) end as ScheduleMod,
           isnull(ddaWC.TMpercent,1)  as  TerritoryMod, 
           case when convert(int,ddaWC.SchedPercent) = 0 or ddaWC.SchedPercent is not null 
                then (isnull(ddaWC.archexMod,1) 
                         * (convert(decimal(5,2),isnull(ddaWC.SchedPercent,1)))) 
                         * isnull(ddaWC.TMpercent,1)
                when ddaWC.SchedPercent is null 
                then 1 END as EffectiveMod
    WHERE dbo.tblCompanyLocations.CompanyGUID = '29634AF7-D0A2-473D-9574-405C23E10F02' 
          AND dbo.tblQuotes.LineGUID = '1CB72920-B3FC-4822-8030-37B50A2810EB' 
) AS ConditionalColumns
```

Comment: Outer Apply against a Subquery!  awesome. Did not know you could do that.

Comment: @CharlesBretana yes, that's great! I use this often for calculated values to avoid repeated code. It allows e.g. something similar to an alias in a where.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

somewhere before code:

```
Declare @compGuid char(37) = '29634AF7-D0A2-473D-9574-405C23E10F02' 
Declare @lineGuid char(37) = '1CB72920-B3FC-4822-8030-37B50A2810EB'
```

and modify From Clause in SQL statement to define aliases
  `cl` for `tblCompanyLocations`,   and
  `q` for `tblQuotes`
then the case in the Select clause of the SQL code could be reduced to:

```
 case when cl.CompanyGUID = @compGuid 
          and q.LineGUID = @lineGuid  
      then isnull(ddaWC.archexMod,1) end ExperienceMod, 

 case when cl.CompanyGUID = @compGuid 
          and q.LineGUID = @lineGuid          
      then case when cast(ddawc.premModTtl as int) > 0
                then (1 + ddaWC.premschmod / ddawc.premModTtl)
                else 1 end end ScheduleMod,

 case when cl.CompanyGUID = @compGuid 
         and q.LineGUID = @lineGuid
      then isnull(ddaWC.TMpercent,1) end TerritoryMod, 

 case when cl.CompanyGUID = @compGuid 
         and q.LineGUID = @lineGuid
      then case when cast(ddaWC.SchedPercent as int) = 0 
                   then isnull(ddaWC.archexMod,1) 
                       * cast(ddaWC.SchedPercent as decimal(5,2)))
                       * isnull(ddaWC.TMpercent,1)
                when ddaWC.SchedPercent is null 
                   then 1 end end EffectiveMod
```

which is a bit more readable... (check the logic though)

Comment: You did the heavy part and cleaned the logic. +1 from my side... I think, the best was to combine yours and mine :-)

Comment: @Shnugo, (get the sp right this time!)  Thx! I learned something ... I did not know you could run outer apply against a subquery. Thought it was only for UDFs.